# I am having some trouble getting the camera example to run on qt

Tags: qt, camera

I am trying to run the camera example on qt and I have no idea why it is not working the error message that comes up when I try to run it is:

```
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.camera"
```

I am new to qt and I don't know why it is not working any help would really be appreciated I have been trying to fix this for 2 days now I am using at 5.7 on ubunto 16.0

this is not a duplicate question please don't mark it as one as I have already tried the solution you have just mentioned

Comment: try with: `sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5-plugins`

Comment: @eylIanesc have tried that already it does not work

Comment: For a next time you have to point out everything you have tried, and if you have tried the solutions of another OS question then you should also point it out, so the community will look for other solutions :-), you must provide all the information so that we can help you the best way. Have you run  `sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`?